# Need to click submit twice and add some character

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, phpmailer

This is the feedbackform.php: (using phpmailer)

```
        <?php
                if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $message = 'Full Name:  ' . $_POST['fullname'] . '<br />
                Subject:    ' . $_POST['subject'] . '<br />
                Phone:  ' . $_POST['phone'] . '<br />
                Email:  ' . $_POST['emailid'] . '<br />
                Comments:   ' . $_POST['comments'] . '
                ';
        require "PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php"; //include phpmailer class
        // Instantiate Class  
        $mail = new PHPMailer();

        // Set up SMTP  
        $mail->IsSMTP();                // Sets up a SMTP connection  
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;         // Connection with the SMTP does require authorization    
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "tsl";      // Connect using a TLS connection  
        $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";  //Gmail SMTP server address
        $mail->Port = 587;  //Gmail SMTP port
        //$mail->Encoding = '7bit';
        // Authentication  
        $mail->Username = "abc@abc.com"; // Your full Gmail address
        $mail->Password = "abc"; // Your Gmail password
        // Compose
        $mail->SetFrom($_POST['emailid'], $_POST['fullname']);
        $mail->AddReplyTo($_POST['emailid'], $_POST['fullname']);
        $mail->Subject = "New Contact Form Enquiry";      // Subject (which isn't required)  
        $mail->MsgHTML($message);

        // Send To  
        $mail->AddAddress("abc@gmail.com", "abc"); // Where to send it - Recipient
        $result = $mail->Send();  // Send!  
        $message = $result ? 'Successfully Sent!' : 'Sending Failed!';
        unset($mail);
    }
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
            <meta name="description" content="">
            <meta name="author" content="">
            <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

            <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>

            <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
            <link href="public/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

            <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
            <link href="public/customCss/starter-template.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="public/bootstrapValidation/css/formValidation.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

            <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
            <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
            <![endif]-->
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="panelc">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-8">
                            <div class="thumbnail1">

                                <div>
                                    <form id="registration-form" method="post" class="form-horizontal" name="registration-form" action="" autocomplete="off">


                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="fullname">Name</label>

                                            <div class="col-sm-8 selectContainer">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fullname" name="fullname" placeholder="Your name"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="emailid">Email</label>

                                            <div class="col-sm-8 selectContainer">
                                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailid" name="emailid" placeholder="Your name"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="subject">Subject</label>

                                            <div class="col-sm-8 selectContainer">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Your name"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="phone">phone</label>

                                            <div class="col-sm-8 selectContainer">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Your name"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="comments">Message</label>

                                            <div class="col-sm-8 selectContainer">
                                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comments" name="comments"></textarea>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-6">
                                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit" value="Submit">
                                                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                    <div>
                                        <p><?php if (!empty($message)) echo $message; ?></p>
                                    </div>  

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </body>



        <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
        <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="public/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <script src="public/bootstrapValidation/js/framework/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="public/customScript/validateform.js"></script>
        <script src="public/bootstrapValidation/js/formValidation.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

1. I need to submit this form, I need to click the submit button twice which means first to validate the form then add some character and click again submit send out the email using phpmailer.
2. if I hide the validate function I can submit directly which is          `<script src="public/customScript/validateform.js"></script>` no need click twice.
3. How I can modified the code with validate form together with one click?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your javascript is intercepting the form submission, validating, but then not continuing with the submission if the validation succeeds, so the problem is in your validation, not the PHP or HTML parts. If the validation fails, then of course it should fail to submit - that's the point of the validation.

While I'm here, don't do this:

```
$mail->SetFrom($_POST['emailid'], $_POST['fullname']);
```

It will cause your messages to fail SPF checks. Put that info in the message body and the reply-to (as you're doing), but set the From address to be your own address, not the submitter's, like this:

```
$mail->SetFrom("abc@gmail.com", "abc");
$mail->AddReplyTo($_POST['emailid'], $_POST['fullname']);
$mail->AddAddress("abc@gmail.com", "abc");
```

This means that the from address is not forged and will not fail SPF checks, but you wil be able to reply directly to the submitter.

Comment: which means `$mail->SetFrom($_POST['emailid'], $_POST['fullname']);` is my information my email and name? and the reply-to also my info?

Comment: No, that info is of the person that is submitting the form. Your info is in the `addAddress` call; use the same address, like `setFrom("abc@gmail.com", "abc")` and leave the reply-to as it is. I will edit my answer to be clearer.